# Delay in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm having trouble delaying a function in Meteor that returns a message from a collection in the database. Right now, in the MeteorPad example link below, a message is posted from the user and it is displayed and faded in to everyone in the display.

[MeteorPad Project Example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/32rHhkm6NmdxSsTt4/Copy%20of%20Test)

**JS**

```
Template.textDisplay.helpers({
message: function () {
return Database.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });
     }
});


Database.insert({
  text: message,
  date: new Date()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="textDisplay">  
<div class="secret-display">
{{secret.text}}
</div>
</template>
```

Unfortunately if many people are sending a message at the same time the message can't be seen as there isn't enough time for the fade to finish.. it would need a 1 second delay between messages with some sort of queue.

I have tried setInterval for the delay which did not work in this case as a queue is needed. Is a queue of collections possible?

Comment: Why not display all messages created in the past 15 seconds instead of just the most recent one?

Comment: @royhowie Mostly just trying to see if it's possible to delay a helper after a certain amount of time. I figured a queue would be best for this situation. I could show all the messages created in the past 15 seconds but it still wouldn't have time to fade in before it executes the next bunch of messages - I want every message to be guaranteed to be seen even if a queue needs to be formed

Comment: What are you using to have the messages fade away? Is there an event you could use to get a new message once the fade has occurred?

Answer (score 1):

Using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` in the helper won't work. You need to use it in `onCreated` or `onRendered`, and then pass it to the helper with a `Session` or `ReactiveVar`

Comment: Following what you said, this should have worked (first 12 lines of client/app.js)

http://meteorpad.com/pad/nsXJb7DQEoyDXMMTu/Test%20Two

Comment: Sorry, that link is taking a long time to load for me

Comment: //client only code
Template.textDisplay.helpers({
  secret: function() {
    return Session.get('selectedPlayer');
  }
});

Template.textDisplay.onRendered(function () {
    
  var secretIn = Secrets.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });
  
  Session.set('selectedPlayer', secretIn);

});

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. `{{secret}}` should update once when `textDisplay` rendered. Then you can add on top of it your timing logic